# printing out elements of an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong ... I am writing a program to play the game quatro, which is a board game kind of like tic tac tow. In the game their are 16 unique pieces in which each piece has four "traits". (Tall or Short , Black or White , Hollow or Filled, Square or Circle)

I created a structure "pieces" in which "traits" is a member. I refer to traits as W for white, T for Tall, H or hollow ....

Anyway, I am just trying to create an array which holds all available pieces and displays them in a separate scaled down program. However I can't seem to print out the elements of the available array.

the error i am getting is

error: not match for 'operator <<' in std:cout << available[0]'

Here is what I am trying now ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Pieces{

string traits;

};

int main()
{
  Pieces p1;
p1.traits = "WSHR";

Pieces p2;
p2.traits = "BSHR";

Pieces p3;
p3.traits = "WTHR";

Pieces p4;
p4.traits = "BTHR";

Pieces available [4] = {p1.traits,p2.traits,p3.traits,p4.traits};

cout << available[0];


return 0;
```

}

I added a bunch of library's hoping that was the problem. When I dereference the available array ( &available[0] ) the address prints out but I can't seem to figure out how to print the value in the first slot of the array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `available` supposed to be an array of `Pieces` or `string`s? Because you're initializing the elements with `string`s.

Comment: In case you were unaware, `Pieces available[4] = { p1, p2, p3, p4 };`  is creating a copy of the original four pieces. If you don't need two copies of everything then just write the array without the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *error: not match for 'operator <<' in std:cout << available[0]'*

You have to define a `std::ostream& operator(std::ostream&, const Pieces&)` operator to print out `Pieces` directly:

```
std::ostream& operator(std::ostream& os, const Pieces& pcs) {
    os << pcs.traits;
    return os;
}
```

Alternatively you can simply output the `traits` member from the `struct Pieces` directly:

```
std::cout << available[0].traits;
```

Comment: Yeah or `cout << available[0].traits`

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I overlooked that ... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because the array `available` contains objects of type `Pieces`, with `cout << available[0]` you're trying to pass a `Pieces` object to `operator<<` of `std::cout`.

But `cout::operator<<` is not overloaded for the type `Pieces` so it doesn't know what to do.

Either overload the `operator<<`<sup>[1]</sup> or simply output the string inside that struct:

```
cout << available[0].traits;
```

<sup>[1]</sup> See [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395)'s answer for an example.

Answer (score -1):

You should overload the '<<'operator (output stream operator), or output the 'traits' member. Also, you can use a custom constructor to make them easier to initialize, and even use the std::vector container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Pieces{
    Pieces(){} // default c'tor
    Pieces(const string& t)
        : traits(t) {}

    string traits;

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, const Pieces& p);
};

// overload the output stream operator for convenience
ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, const Pieces& p)
{
    stream << p.traits;
    return stream;
}


int main()
{
    Pieces p1("WSHR");  // neater if you write a constructor overload that inits the contents
    Pieces p2("BSHR");
    Pieces p3("WTHR");
    Pieces p4("BTHR");

    Pieces available[4] = { p1, p2, p3, p4 };
    // Or you could init the elements directly in the array; 
    Pieces a2[1] = { Pieces("WSHR") };

    cout << available[0] << endl; 

    // This is my favorite way to declare and init the array
    vector<Pieces> avail = { Pieces("WSHR"), Pieces("BSHR"), Pieces("WTHR"), Pieces("BTHR") };
    cout << avail[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `friend` declaration for `operator<<()` isn't needed for a `struct`. You are aware of this, aren't you?

Comment: I just attempted compilation without it and it *is* required in this case (VS2013).

Comment: Strange behavior, I can't see any evidence why a `friend` declaration should be necessary for this case.

Comment: @axon Not in a decent compiler: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/966cee84a705faae

Comment: Compiling the above code without `friend` gives this error: "error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters". Implying that another `operator <<` is matched by the compiler.